# Reading/Writing file and then creating .exe file in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I am completely new to Fortran but have been given these files (see below) which reads an input text file, uses the Fortran code to calculate a set of values then writes them into an output text file. The programme works for all cases except Case 4, 8 and 11, producing the error:

```
forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit 5, file C:\temp\sharclab\i_capa.txt

Image              PC        Routine            Line        Source             
Capacity.exe       0046B6EE  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
Capacity.exe       00468940  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
Capacity.exe       00411C9A  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
Capacity.exe       004118C7  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
Capacity.exe       0040C416  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
Capacity.exe       0040BBDA  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
Capacity.exe       0040714C  _MAIN__                    16  main.F90
Capacity.exe       0046EB78  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
Capacity.exe       004528E0  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
kernel32.dll       7C817067  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

I will post the code below and if anyone can help me solve this I would very much appreciate it, thank you!

First file (only the particular parts that don't function):

```
Case (4)

    DiamRoul = abs(DonneesRlt(1))
    DiamPrim = abs(DonneesRlt(2))
    NbRoul = abs(int(DonneesRlt(3)))
    NbRangRoul = abs(int(DonneesRlt(4)))
    LongEff = abs(DonneesRlt(5))

    If ((NbRoul==0).OR.(DiamPrim==0)) Then
        CodeErr = 1
    else ! Calcul si nb corps roulants différent de zéro

        Gamma = DiamRoul / DiamPrim

        FC = 17.24553 * ((1 + (1.04 * ((1 - Gamma) / (1 + Gamma)) 
 &      ** P1) ** P3) ** P4) * (((Gamma ** P2) * (1 - Gamma)  
 &      ** P5) / ((1 + Gamma) ** P11))

        ChargeDynSNR = FC * ((NbRangRoul * LongEff) ** P6) 
 &      * (NbRoul ** P7) * (DiamRoul ** P5) * 1.1293

        ChargeDynISO = FC * ((NbRangRoul * LongEff) ** P6)  
 &      * (NbRoul ** P7) * (DiamRoul ** P5) * 1.1

        ChargeStaSNR = 4.4 * (1 - Gamma) * NbRangRoul * NbRoul 
 &      * LongEff * DiamRoul

        ChargeStaISO = ChargeStaSNR   

    End If


Case (8)

    DiamRoul = abs(DonneesRlt(1))
    DiamPrim = abs(DonneesRlt(2))
    NbRoul = abs(int(DonneesRlt(3)))
    LongEff = abs(DonneesRlt(4))

    If ((NbRoul==0).OR.(DiamPrim==0)) Then
        CodeErr = 1
    else  ! Calcul si nb corps roulants différent de zéro       

        Gamma = DiamRoul / DiamPrim

        FC = 34.48913 * 0.85 * (Gamma ** P2)

        ChargeDynSNR = FC * (LongEff ** P6) * (NbRoul ** P7) * 
 &                      (DiamRoul ** P5) * 1

        ChargeDynISO = ChargeDynSNR

        ChargeStaSNR = 22 * (1 - Gamma) * NbRoul * LongEff 
 &                      * DiamRoul

        ChargeStaISO = ChargeStaSNR
    End If

Case (11)

    DiamRoul = abs(DonneesRlt(1))
    NbRoul = abs(int(DonneesRlt(2)))
    LongEff = abs(DonneesRlt(3))
    DiamPrim = abs(DonneesRlt(4))
    AngleDeg = 45
    AngleMin = 0
    AngleSec = 0
    NbRoul = abs(int(NbRoul / 2))
    NbRangRoul = 2
    DiamSpher = 0

    If (NbRoul==0) Then
        CodeErr = 1
    else ! Calcul si nb corps roulants différent de zéro

        Alpha = pi * (AngleDeg + (AngleMin / 60) + (AngleSec / 
 &              3600)) / 180

        If (DiamPrim==0) Then
            DiamPrim = (DiamSpher - DiamRoul) * DCos(Alpha)
        End If

        Gamma = (DiamRoul * DCos(Alpha)) / DiamPrim

        FC = 17.24553 * ((1 + (1.04 * ((1 - Gamma) / (1 + Gamma)) 
 &      ** P1) ** P3) ** P4) * (((Gamma ** P2) * (1 - Gamma)  
 &      ** P5) / ((1 + Gamma) ** P11))

        ChargeDynSNR = FC * ((NbRangRoul * LongEff * DCos(Alpha)) 
 &      ** P6) * (NbRoul ** P7) *   (DiamRoul ** P5) * 1.1

        ChargeDynISO = ChargeDynSNR

        ChargeStaSNR = 4.4 * (1 - Gamma) * NbRangRoul * NbRoul * 
 &      LongEff * DiamRoul * DCos(Alpha)

        ChargeStaISO = ChargeStaSNR
    End If

End Select  

!     Arrondissement de toutes les charges calculées
if (ChargeDynSNR.LE.0) then
    ChargeDynSNR = 0
    ChargeDynSNRArr = 0
else
    Call Arron(TypeRlt, ChargeDynSNR, CapaArr)
    ChargeDynSNRArr = CapaArr
end if

if (ChargeDynISO.LE.0) then
    ChargeDynISO = 0
    ChargeDynISOArr = 0
else
    Call Arron(TypeRlt, ChargeDynISO, CapaArr)
    ChargeDynISOArr = CapaArr
end if

if (ChargeStaSNR.LE.0) then
    ChargeStaSNR = 0
    ChargeStaSNRArr = 0
else
    Call Arron(TypeRlt, ChargeStaSNR, CapaArr)
    ChargeStaSNRArr = CapaArr
end if

if (ChargeStaISO.LE.0) then
    ChargeStaISO = 0
    ChargeStaISOArr = 0
else
    Call Arron(TypeRlt, ChargeStaISO, CapaArr)
    ChargeStaISOArr = CapaArr
endif

    !     Toutes les charges calculées sont multipliées par 10.
Charges(1) = ChargeDynSNR * 10
Charges(2) = ChargeDynISO * 10
Charges(3) = ChargeStaSNR * 10
Charges(4) = ChargeStaISO * 10
ChargesArr(1) = ChargeDynSNRArr * 10
ChargesArr(2) = ChargeDynISOArr * 10
ChargesArr(3) = ChargeStaSNRArr * 10
ChargesArr(4) = ChargeStaISOArr * 10

return
END subroutine
```

Second file (main.F90):

```
program main
implicit  none

integer TypeRlt
    !   Entrees/Sorties
real*8 DonneesRlt(15)
    !   Sorties 
integer CodeErr
real*8 Charges(4)
integer ChargesArr(4)

open (5, FILE='C:\temp\sharclab\i_capa.txt')
open (6, FILE='C:\temp\sharclab\o_capa.txt')

read(5,*) TypeRlt
read(5,*) DonneesRlt

write(*,*) TypeRlt
write(*,*) DonneesRlt

close(5)
!TypeRlt = 5


call Capacites(TypeRlt,DonneesRlt,Charges,ChargesArr,CodeErr)

write(6,*) ChargesArr(1)
write(6,*) ChargesArr(2)
write(6,*) ChargesArr(3)
write(6,*) ChargesArr(4)
close(6)

write(*,*) ChargesArr(1)
write(*,*) ChargesArr(2)
write(*,*) ChargesArr(3)
write(*,*) ChargesArr(4)

end
```

I apologise if the code hasn't been copied in properly..The two text files are simply a vertical list of values for which if there isn't 15 value present (required for this Fortran programme), a value of 0 is put in it's place.

As this programme functions correctly for another cases (which I haven't posted here). I don't understand why it doesn't do the same for these cases..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the units from 5 and 6 to some other values: Usually unit 5 is associated with the standard input (see, e.g. http://docs.cray.com/books/S-3695-35/html-S-3695-35/pdollsmg.html)

EDIT:

How does the i_capa.txt file look like --- does it really hold two values in two lines?

Can you run the following program and see if you can read the file in:

```
implicit  none

integer TypeRlt
real*8 DonneesRlt(15)

open (5, FILE='C:\temp\sharclab\i_capa.txt')

read(1,*) TypeRlt
read(1,*) DonneesRlt

print*, TypeRlt
print*, DonneesRlt
```

If this fails, would you please post the exact contents of your `i_capa.txt` file.

I suspect you either don't have the file, or it has less than 15 real values for `DonneesRlt` or it contains something else.

Comment: Thanks for your reply also but I tried changing the values and that didn't seem to change anything..

Comment: I've managed to figure it out and it is actually a problem in another piece of code that links to it in Python. Thanks for all your help and it's actually helped me understand things about Fortran as I don't usually use it at all!

Answer (score 1):

There are only two calls to read, and both try to read the file i_capa.txt. When you see the error message: 'end-of-file during read' you can be pretty sure that i_capa.txt is shorter than the program expects. So my first guess is that i_capa.txt wasn't correctly set up when your program began execution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I really don't understand why this would be as it works perfectly for all the other cases I have.

Comment: Have you actually *looked* into i_capa.txt to see what's there? That is, can you put a breakpoint just before the read of 5 and then look into the file when the breakpoint is taken. It has to be the case that you have come to the end of the file at that point because that's what the error message tells us.

Comment: To continue: it seems that other parts of the program have read straight through the file at this point. Can you put a rewind 5 in there just before the read of 5 and see what happens? Also: can you edit or just print i_capa.txt before  you run your code to confirm that what you expect is really there?